# TypeError: Invalid value used in weak set at WeakSet.add (<anonymous>)

Tags: vue.js, unit-testing, jestjs, wrapper, mount

- I have been trying to write a test file for a vue component but i am not uderstanding where am
  i going wrong.Im new to this unit testing but i have been searching the internet for a while
  without result*

  [vue component file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DRK1O.png)
  [test file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rIL7p.png)
  [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vw1Vq.png)

Comment: In the test you are importing your component as a named component (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export) but your component actually exports as a default export. In simple terms use `import SubNavigation from '@/components/Navigation/SubNavigation'`

Also next time please place the code in here instead of in screenshots, makes it much easier to read.

Comment: @Seph - you should add this as an answer that can be accepted. I found it very useful for debugging some code I'd inherited. It would have taken hours without finding your answer.

Comment: @Ambulare done. :)

Answer (score 1):

In the test you are importing your component as a named component (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export) but your component actually exports as a default export. In simple terms use `import SubNavigation from '@/components/Navigation/SubNavigation'`.

Also next time please place the code in here instead of in screenshots, makes it much easier to read.